# How to use JavaScript reflection with ES6 standard to fulfill the REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, reflection

I just find the javascript can do some reflection in standard EC6.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)

I wonder whether or not can do reflect in user defined objects and put it on REST service?

For example, my class is:

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

identity: 'user',
connection: 'myLocalDisk',

attributes: {

  first_name: 'string',
  last_name: 'string'
}
name: function(){
     return this.attributes.first_name+" "+this.attributes.last_name;
}
});

var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

identity: 'pet',
connection: 'myLocalMySql',

attributes: {
   name: 'string',
   breed: 'string'
}
somename: function(){
    return something;
}
});
```

This is comes from:
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js

I want to implement REST api for express framework like:

```
http://loalhost:3000/api/?class=ClassName&method=function&filter=json_filter
```

for the user example:

```
http://loalhost:3000/api/?class=User&method=name&filter={"first_name":"John"}
```

Then there will be a json files with list of users name "John" with give out.
like:

```
{"users":[{"name": "John Smith"},{"name":"John Maylar"},{"name":"John Hakinson"}],
 "stat": "OK",
  "code":200
 }
```

Of course the class can modify, for this case it can be User or Pet.

Does javascript reflection can fulfill the rest service like this and how to do it? can you give me a similar example about this?

Comment: There is no EC6. It's called ES6. Did your autocorrect do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. `Reflect` is a better `eval`, or maybe "operators as functions". Are you looking for proxies? And what does this have to do with REST? What do you mean by "*reflection can fulfill the rest service*"? What are you referring to by "*like this*"?

Comment: @Bergi I want to auto REST service. I mean I have some class models, which is unknown.(I know some of them but in the future I may add hundreds of models, I do not want to write all service by hand.) I want to use reflect to print json string presentation of that class objects. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: To create models (classes) on the fly, and programmatically, is trivial in JavaScript and does not need any ES6 `Reflect` feature. Just use a closure.

Comment: But I still don't understand what you need. What's the input? How would the usage of your automagic think look like? What do you expect it create, how does the output look like? There is some code in your question, but I can't see which role it plays in your problem.

Comment: @Bergi I have models. I would make the models can auto service as apis, as the request.

Comment: @Bergi The input is rest request from user, the output is the json string of the object. The code is the examples of the inputs and outputs I want. The models will be defined by other developer. The task is use reflection to extra the information form unknown models and make it can accept basic REST service.

Comment: So you'd basically have a collection `var models = {User, Pet}` and then simply do `if (models.hasOwnProperty(req.params.class)) new models[req.params.class]()[req.params.method]();`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think should be similar like this.

Comment: Yup. I don't know what exactly you need, and don't have experience with waterfront, but I can tell you that's you won't need more reflection than that. If you need further help, it would help me if you could formulate the code for creating the REST service with some examples of known models (I can then abstract that to unknown models).

Comment: @Bergi Your code is just for the new models, I want to print the models or object properties already store in collections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get stack traces for XHR calls in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265474/how-to-get-stack-traces-for-xhr-calls-in-a-browser)